# Appending form using angular js

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to append form using angularJs. I am very beginner to angular js. I am using CakePHP. What I have been able to do so far is I have successfully appended the forms with some default values on clicking 'add' button, but what I want to do next is to be able to reset values of appended form to `''` and to change 'input name' for every form fields. I don't know how to acquire that. Any help will be very appreciable.

My basic code in php is:

```
<div data-ng-repeat='choice in choices' class="other_tenant_class{{choice.id}}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 label-form">
                <label>Name</label> </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                <label >
                    <div class="toggle toggle-light ot_name_visibility"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('name_visibility', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control switch_size_ot_name',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                        'name' => 'data['.$i.'][name_visibility]',
                        'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['name_visibility']
                    )); ?>

                </label>   </div> </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
                'class' => 'form-control other_tenants_name',
                'label' => false,
                'name' => 'data['.$i.'][name]',
                'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['name']
            ));?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 label-form">
                <label>Age</label> </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                <label >
                    <div class="toggle toggle-light ot_age_visibility"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('age_visibility', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control switch_size_ot_age',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                        'name' => 'data['.$i.'][age_visibility]',
                        'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['age_visibility']
                    )); ?>

                </label>   </div> </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('age', array(
                'class' => 'form-control other_tenants_age',
                'name' => 'data['.$i.'][age]',
                'label' => false,
                'type' => 'number',
                'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['age']
            ));?>
        </div> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 label-form">
                <label>Relation</label> </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                <label >
                    <div class="toggle toggle-light ot_relation_visibility"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('relation_visibility', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control switch_size_ot_relation',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                        'name' => 'data['.$i.'][relation_visibility]',
                        'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['relation_visibility']
                    )); ?>

                </label>   </div> </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('relation', array(
                'class' => 'form-control other_tenants_relations',
                'label' => false,
                'name' => 'data['.$i.'][relation]',
                'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['relation']
            ));?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 label-form">
                <label>Years Known</label> </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                <label >
                    <div class="toggle toggle-light ot_years_known_visibility"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('years_known_visibility', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control switch_size_ot_years_known',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                        'name' => 'data['.$i.'][years_known_visibility]',
                        'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['years_known_visibility']
                    )); ?>

                </label>   </div> </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('years_known', array(
                'class' => 'form-control other_tenants_years_known',
                'label' => false,
                'name' => 'data['.$i.'][years_known]',
                'type' => 'number',
                'default' => $otherTenants[$i]['years_known']
            ));?>
        </div> </div>

    <?php }
    }
    ?>

    <button type='button' class="remove" ng-show="$first" ng-click="removeChoice()">Remove Field</button>
</div>
<button type='button' class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
</div>
```

AngularJs Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('shanidkvApp', []);    

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];    
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var originalItemNo = $scope.choices.length;
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});                 
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };      
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where `$i` is coming from, but it looks as if you are trying to use it as a PHP iterator offset inside a `ng-repeat` loop.

Note that PHP becomes static once the page has been loaded by the browser. Therefore, you need to work exclusively with AngularJS, which provides `{{$index}}` as an iterator offset. See [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for more information.

The code for adding input fields should look similar to the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('{{$index}}.age', array(
    'class' => 'form-control other_tenants_age',
    'label' => false,
    'type' => 'number',
    'ng-model' => "choice.age"
 )); ?>
```

For this to work, you have to pre-load your `choices` array. A simple approach is to do it in your `ng-controller` declaration:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init='choices=<?=json_encode($otherTenants)?>'>
```

Not sure if I got the `choices` vs `$otherTenants` meaning right, but just consider the above as an example on how you should structure your code.

If you find that CakePHP is getting in the way and making things complicated in your AngularJs powered view, get rid of `$this->Form->input()` and try coding the form in plain HTML.